# conversion from string to integer vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this simple program that is giving me an error.  The code is as follows

```
    Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
    Dim FullName As String = "" 
    Dim Address As String = "" 
    Dim CityStateZip As String = "" 
    Dim Stoves As Integer 
    Dim Refrigerators As Integer 
    Dim Dishwashers As Integer 

    INPUT_DATA(FullName, Address, CityStateZip, Stoves, Refrigerators, Dishwashers)
    MsgBox(FullName, Address, CityStateZip)

End Sub
Sub INPUT_DATA(ByRef Name As String, ByRef Address As String, ByRef CSZ As String, ByRef Stoves As Integer, ByRef Refrigerators As Integer, ByRef Dishwashers As Integer)
    If txtName.Text = "" Then
        Name = InputBox("Please enter a name!")
    Else
        Name = txtName.Text
    End If
    If txtAddress.Text = "" Then
        Address = InputBox("Please enter an address!")
    Else
        Address = txtAddress.Text
    End If
    If txtCSZ.Text = "" Then
        CSZ = InputBox("Please enter City, State, Zip!")
    Else
        CSZ = txtCSZ.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

When I try to messagebox fullname, address and citystatezip it keeps giving me an error saying that it can't convert the address to an integer.  I declared all three of those variables as strings and in the program when I ran it I entered A B and C in those three textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for MsgBox (as VS will show you via Intellisense) is:

```
 MsgBox (Prompt, Optional ByVal Buttons As Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle = _ 
         OkOnly, Optional ByVal Title As Object = Nothing)
```

When you call MsgBox your second parameter should be an Integer indicating the style.  Try This:

```
  MsgBox (FullName & " - " & Address & " - " & CityStateZip)
```

or add linefeeds if you choose.